# Can i get order data using Big Commerce API from my BC store even when i change the DNS of the store and migrated it from BC to OC?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have migrated my store from BC to OpenCart.I don't want to down the site, so i will change the DNS of my site.But can i get data using Big Commerce API as they use the store URL and after changing DNS that URL will map to another server instead of BC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still access the store via the API. Just move the store back to a temporary/".mybigcommerce.com" url. You can only access the store while you are still paying for it. If the store is terminated or put on hold, the data will be inaccessible.

This is a better question for BigCommerce support rather than StackOverflow.